# ios - whatsapp url scheme doesn't work when adding hashtag (%23)

Tags: ios, angularjs, whatsapp, ios-urlsheme

I have an angular based website with a `whatsapp` share button using the `url-scheme`.

I'm trying to open whatsapp with text containing a URL. As in angular based sites, the site name contains an `hashtag (%23)`. Like the following example:

```
whatsapp://send?text=Hello All%0AHow are you%0A%0Ahttp://www.example.com/%23/login
```

This works perfectly on android device.

However, on iOS, the whatsapp get opened but the text isn't imbeeded in the input area. (specifically `version 9` as I only have devices of that version)

Any Suggestions ?

Comment: Did you found an answer to that? i'm having similar issue...